# SQL insert into select Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field '' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, sql

I have a table that contains `idCourse, idCoureur, time1, time2, time3`
and I would like to insert a new line.

```
INSERT INTO  chrono (idCourse, idCoureur)
SELECT  idCourse, idCoureur
FROM     dossard
```

I want `time1, time2, time3` to be null, but I get an error message because `time1, time2, time3` don't have values. How do I fix that?

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field '' doesn't have a default value

Comment: So what did you already try?

Comment: @GutT not a lot of things because I have no idea and i don't know what to try sorry

Comment: could you please share table's chrono DDL ?

Comment: _null or empty_? NULL means no value. A time can't be 'empty'.

Comment: **NOTE** Please put the error message in the question

Answer (score 0):

set the column as nullable.
Maybe you set NOT NULL when you created.

ALTER TABLE chrono
ALTER COLUMN [time1] SMALLDATETIME NULL

Comment: yes thanks it works fine now 
have a good day